# tabBox in shiny - get title above tabs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Does anyone know how to make the title of a tabBox go above the tabs in a shinydashboard app? For example, in the figure below, the title is on the right, but I would like it to go on top of the box.

[image]

Code for this tabBox:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
  ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"), dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
tabBox(title = HTML("Hello friend<br>"),
                      tabPanel("merp", "hi there"),
                      tabPanel("derp", "hello"),
                      tabPanel("herp", "howdy")
      ))
    )

)
  
  
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    # The currently selected tab from the first box
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
      input$tabset1
    })
  }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server

)
```

Comment: please provide a reprex

Comment: Apologies, just edited the text to make a complete reprex

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but just a thought; can you but the `tabBox` object inside a `box` object ? You would then provide a title for the `box` but **no title** for the `tabBox`. I don't have time to test this, otherwise I would work on a solution, but it may be easy enough for you to try.

Comment: @steveb I just tried this actually, and it worked! You beat me to writing out the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Marissa good to hear. You may want to post your solution which I think you are planning on. It will likely help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who might look for the solution here, a pretty simple fix was to put the tabBox (with no title) inside of a box with a title:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"), dashboardSidebar(),
                   dashboardBody(
                     fluidRow(box(title = HTML("Hello friend<br>"),
                                  tabBox(
                                    tabPanel("merp", "hi there"),
                                    tabPanel("derp", "hello"),
                                    tabPanel("herp", "howdy"))
                     ))
                   )
                   
)  

server = function(input, output) {
  # The currently selected tab from the first box
  output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
    input$tabset1
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is the side argument e.g

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      title = "First tabBox",
      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
      id = "tabset1", height = "250px",side = 'right',
      tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
)
))

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"), dashboardSidebar(), body),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # The currently selected tab from the first box
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
      input$tabset1
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: This doesn't put the title above the tabs, just moves it to right hand side.